# Nginx & PHP-FPM: Query parameters won't be passed to PHP

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, querystring

I am currently setting up a machine for local development using Vagrant. Everything runs as it should, expect query parameters aren't passed to PHP on subpages.

That means on `www.example.com/?a=b`, the query parameter is accessible, but on `www.example.com/subpage/?a=b` it's not.

The general reply I found using Google for this problem is to modify the `try_files` directive, but that isn't working for me. I've also checked the `request_order` & `variables_order` in `php.ini` – everything is setup correctly there.

This is my config:

```
 server {
     listen                80;
     server_name           example.com www.example.com;
     root                  /var/www/public;

     location / {
         index   index.html index.htm index.php;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
         include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
         include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     }

     sendfile off;
}
```

Since I don't know much about server setup & administration, I am hitting a brick wall here, still here are a few things I also checked:

- `$query_string` is set in `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` as `fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;` which seems correct to me.
- The path to `fastcgi_params` is correct

Since it works when not being on a subpage, I am now suspecting the location blocks not matching, but I really don't understand how this could be the case – please help.

Comment: It's a long shot, but make sure you're not being redirected before you handle the request. You can easily see this in Chrome's DevTools Network tab, use Preserve log.

Comment: @DaliborKarlović Thanks for the suggestion – I checked & I am not being redirected.

Comment: Turning on debugging and watching the log would help. http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html . Most distributions come with debugging pre-compiled.

Comment: Could you make this work? @Sven

Answer (score 12):

You need to use $is_args for question mark & $args or $query_string for query string afterwards question mark.

here it's the last combination.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;
```

Also be sure that you have set

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
```

then pass it fastcgi;

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

Comment: check for $is_args in documentation. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html

Comment: Cool, I think I understand. Still, query string are not present on subpages.

Comment: Man, `$is_args$query_string` saved my life for a query parameters in pages. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A query string starts with a question mark.

Then set in the second block :

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Remove `include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;` in the first block since you don't have any `fastcgi_pass` directive here.

Comment: Do I need to put this in both location blocks?

Comment: @Sven Why would you put this in the first block ? There's no `fastcgi_pass` directive here.

Comment: Okay I see. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Is the order of the directives in the location block important?

Comment: @Sven No it's not except if your include directive override a previous configuration line using the same directive. Can you clarify the *it doesn't work* ? This really seems to come from your app. Also make sure you are not hitting browser cache when testing.

Comment: Okay, thanks. For clarification:  `_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` is still empty on a subpage with query parameters present (`example.com/subpage/?a=b`). On `example.com?a=b` the query string is present in `_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`. Do I need to do something else that reloading Nginx for changes to take effect?

Comment: @Sven Nothing else than reloading is required.

Comment: Then it's exactly setup according to your answer, but not working, sorry.